# Bazel: Separate output directories for different build options

Tags: bazel

Bazel has different output directories for different compilation modes (fastbuild, opt, dbg) which allows it to keep the release build-cache intact after you compile the app in debug mode. Which is great.

Is it possible to do the same for different compilation options?

My use-case: I have a custom-built C++ symbolic computations system. Each run of the program is one computation. Most computations take a few seconds. But some take minutes. To speed up the latter I unrolled several low-level functions, and now thousands of lines of code are copied to every compilation unit (because the functions are templated). This made a decent effect on computation speed but also slowed down compilation significantly. It really only makes sense to use these optimizations for a small fraction of runs.

So, a put them under a define which I can toggle via `--cxxopt=-DUNROLL_ALL_THE_THINGS`. But whenever I switch from unrolled version to a simple one and back Bazel drops compilation cache. In essence, I've split “opt” mode into two (“opt” and “super-opt”) but I can't make Bazel see it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can use the [`--platform_suffix`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--platform_suffix) option to manually add a suffix to the output directory name. So, you could pass `--platform_suffix=super` whenever you use `--cxxopt=-DUNROLL_ALL_THE_THINGS`.

Comment: I recommend putting both the `--platform_suffix` and `--cxxopt` in a [.bazelrc section](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#--config) so you can toggle both of them with `--config`. Harder to forget, and easier to add more later.

Answer (score 0):

For your different commands, pass `--platform_suffix=your_configuration_name`.

So, if you have a custom dbg configuration, it will be

```
--platform_suffix=dbg-myconfig
```

Similarly for the opt build pass this flag:

```
--platform_suffix=opt-myotherconfig
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify this multiple times... so you can have things like "gcc-dbg", "clang-dbg", "gcc-opt", "clang-opt"???